# Pizza code not working out | C Programming on Cinnamon

Tags: c, char, int, printf, scanf

I am trying to read a name and some answers, the goal is for the program to ask all the questions, deliver the necessary answers and all...

I wonder if you can help me out understand what's wrong, why and how to solve it...

I am on a Mint (Cinnamon) machine and use the terminal for creating files, editing, compiling and running code with touch, nano and gcc.

It's a pretty simple code, just for fun while learning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {

char answer, answer2, name;
int slices;

printf("Do you love Pizza? Please, enter your name:\n\n");
scanf("%c\n\n", &name);
printf("%c loves Pizza!!!\n\n", name);

printf("Are you all right, %c?\n\n", name);
scanf("%c\n\n", &answer);

printf("I am glad you are allright!! :D\n\n"); //it's supposed to be a positive answer!
printf("Do you want some slices now?\n\n");
scanf("%s\n\n", &answer2);

printf("Ah, that's awesome!!\n\n");
printf("And how many slices do you wish?\n\n");
printf("I want ");
scanf("%d\n\n", &slices);

printf("Awesome!!\n\n");
printf("Enjoy your %d Pizza slices!! :D\n\n", slices);
return 0;
}
```

1ˢᵗ Error: It prints out only the first letter of typed info

2ᶮᵈ Error: The second question as well as the fourth does not get done at all and so, prints out the char value (right?)

Result:

```
Do you love Pizza? Please, enter your name:

Finder
F loves Pizza!!!

Are you all right, F?

I am glad you are allright!! :D

Do you want some slices now?

YES
Ah, that's awesome!!

And how many slices do you wish?

I want Awesome!!

Enjoy your 29285 Pizza slices!! :D
```

How to work this out?

Comment: `%c` is the format specifier for a single `char`, you want to use `%s`

Comment: ... and to read a single character in `scanf`.

Comment: I appreciate @TormundGiantsbane? I'll try and change the code to check out the results

Comment: Also `char` stores only a single character. You'll need to use `char answer[xx]` and such, where `xx` is the maximum number of characters.

Comment: Great! I appreciate @FredLarson! Compile with this change as well!

Comment: I set up it like this: "char answer[9], answer2[9], name[9];"

Comment: But for all the scanf's, there's the following kind of error: "warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[9]’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%s\n\n", &name);
         ~^       ~~~~~
"

Comment: Don't use the `&`, as `char[]` will decay to a pointer on its own. And you'd better hope I don't run this and type in `Frederick` as my name -- you still need room for the null terminator.

Comment: Hahaha, there's Pizza for all of us :D

Comment: I am not sure exactly what your comment means. I'll search more info on pointers, that I have heard of before but many years (I studied for some time but mainly sort of basic stuff so it's like to begin), and also try and understand better about null terminator (is it some supposed to be in the code instead of "return 0;"?)

Comment: If you guys know about a good Creative Commons book on C to share, I'll certainly appreciate :D

Comment: I got better what you meant by null character now after searching for the strlen () function from the answer, @FredLarson :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always need to clean the `stdin` buffer everytime you input something to `scanf()` to get rid of `'\n'`. Thats why your program skip the input part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> // needed for strlen() function.

int main()
{
    char name[50];
    char answer, answer2;
    int slices;
    int c; // buffer cleaner.

    printf("Do you love Pizza? Please, enter your name:\n\n");

    if ((fgets(name, 50, stdin)) != NULL)// removing '\n' from the string.
    {
        size_t len = strlen(name);
        if (len > 0 && name[len - 1] == '\n')
            name[--len] = '\0';
    }
    printf("%s loves Pizza!!!\n\n", name);

    printf("Are you all right, %s?\n\n", name);
    getchar();
     while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) // cleaning the buffer
        ;
    // scanf("%c\n\n", &answer);--->  if it is suppossed to be positive answer why store the variable?

    printf("I am glad you are allright!! :D\n\n"); //it's supposed to be a positive answer!
    printf("Do you want some slices now?\n\n");
    scanf("%c", &answer2); // Consider use only one char 'y' or 'n'. Else you have to use a fgets() and store in a string variable.
     while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) // cleaning the buffer
        ;
    printf("Ah, that's awesome!!\n\n");
    printf("And how many slices do you wish?\n\n");
    printf("I want ");
    scanf("%d", &slices);
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) // cleaning the buffer
        ;

    printf("Awesome!!\n\n");
    printf("Enjoy your %d Pizza slices!! :D\n\n", slices);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Much appreciated :D I am typing your code line by line and trying to figure out each chunk and I'll answer back as soon as possible :D

Comment: How about `scanf(" %c", &c);`?

Comment: So, raijin your answer works sweet! I got a better understanding of your code but am sure it'll get better with practice and learning and practice! I really appreciate! :D

Comment: My upvote doesn't show up yet because of reputation points. Am not sure if when I get the 15 points all upvotes I casted'll show up or only newer ones will

Comment: Also, I appreciate each and everyone of you guys! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Dont believe its a good option if the user input more than one char in the `scanf(" %c", &c);` the input will be missed. Also `fflush(stdin)` dont clean properly.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is illegal (Undefined Behaviour and Demons flying out of you nose). The case that the user inputs more than one character isn't a bug in the program, but a problem of the user. Maybe he writes faster the you are able to interpret it, and he is already writing for the next `scanf()`; you should let him do that as long as you can handle it. Let's say the user inputs `f7\n`. It should be accepted as a valid input for both consecutive `scanf()`s.

Comment: Your option is more or less like reimplementing `fgets()` + `sscanf()`.  Use those if you want that (single `\n` terminated lines), and use `scanf()` if you want to read as if reading from a pipe.